# Return a summarized value from a related table via a many to one relationship in Power BI (DAX)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I'm working with PowerBI, but considering this is a Dax question I'd assume this applies to power pivot as well.

Consider the following tables, with the desired result in Table - One:

Table - Many

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 1  | a     |
+----+-------+
| 1  | a     |
+----+-------+
| 1  | a     |
+----+-------+
```

Table - One

```
+----+-----------------------+
| id | minValueFromTableMany |
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  | (Expecting a)         |
+----+-----------------------+
```

I have a relationship setup between the two tables. I'd like to derive a new attribute in 'Table - One' that is simply the min on 'value' in table - many for each matching id.

This would be trivial in any SQL-varient, Python or R.

SQL

```
SELECT
    T1.id
    ,T2.minValueFromTableMany
FROM TableOne T1
    INNER JOIN ( 
                 SELECT MIN(value) as minValueFromTableMany
                 FROM TableMany
                 GROUP BY id
               ( as T2
       ON T1.id = T2.id
```

How do we do this in DAX? Using a min() function simply returns the min(value) for the entire column and is not using the relationship I've setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's even simpler in DAX. You can create a calculated column like this:

```
minValueFromTableMany = CALCULATE(MIN(TableMany[value]),
                            ALLEXCEPT(TableOne, TableOne[id]))
```

This assumes that they have a relationship on the `id` columns.

---

Here's another way to do it that should work with or without the relationship:

```
minValueFromTableMany = CALCULATE(MIN(TableMany[value]),
                            TableMany[id] = EARLIER(TableOne[id]))
```

The `EARLIER` function refers to the earlier row context.

---

You can also use the `MINX` function:

```
minValueFromTableMany = MINX(
                            FILTER(TableMany, TableMany[id] = TableOne[id]),
                            TableMany[value])
```

Comment: seems to have missed this one:
=MINX(RELATEDTABLE(TableMany),TableMany[value])

Comment: Thanks Alexis I'll take a look at this today.